# 'any' type with TypeScript, but strictly truthy

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am looking to do something like this:

```
v.foo = function(val: any){

};
```

the problem is that I can call foo with null, like so:

```
v.foo(null);
```

instead, I would like to declare something like this:

```
v.foo = function(val: truthy){

};
```

where val can be virtually anything, but has to be truthy (non-falsy).

is it possible with TS?

Answer (score 2):

You can define this type as [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) of `object` and primitives alongside with enabling *strictNullChecks*

```
type Truthy = object | string | number | boolean;

function foo(val: Truthy) {

};

foo({ a: 1});
foo('');
foo(1);
foo(new Date());
foo(false);
foo([]);

foo(null); //error
foo(undefined); //error
```

Comment: As a bonus, if you change `boolean` to `true` then `false` will *also* fail to compile, leaving just `''` and `0` in the domain of "falsey things that we can't catch at 'compile' time".

Comment: @SeanVieira you're right, but depends on "falsy" definition :)

Comment: Without `strictNullChecks`, the Ts language cannot help more than other strongly type languages like C#, using guard clauses `if (null) throw`